# One or two possessive apostrophes for two subjects with different possession

Tags: punctuation

'The similarities between Odelle's and Smith’s artistic depictions of women [...]'

OR

'The similarities between Odelle and Smith’s artistic depictions of women [...]'

The point in question regards the apostrophes. One claim is that the first one on Odelle isn't necessary. It seems like this would be true only if Odelle and Smith were collaborating on their art. However, **the intended meaning of the sentence is that both subjects, although similar, each have unique treatment of women in their art.** The word that throws me off is depictions. Because this word is plural perhaps the first claim is true? This way Odelle and Smith could still have unique depictions but share the compound subject possession. Really scratching my head over this one...

Comment: Use two apostrophes and the plural; there are two depictions here: Odelle's depiction and Smith's depiction. Would you say (assuming they weren't under some unified command) *"the French and British army"* or *"the French and British armies"*. You'd use *"armies"*.

Comment: Please see the duplicate question, and its comments and the other questions linked there. If they don't satisfy, please come back and edit this question for clarification.